# Asp.net Proper Authorization Message

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

These are my settings in `web.config`:

```
<location path="Salary.aspx"> 
    <system.web> 
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Salary Admin" /> 
            <deny users="*"/> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web> 
</location>
```

In `web.config` this is working perfectly fine, but, I want to display an appropriate message to the user that he is not authorized and give a link to go back. Instead it's going to the login form directly, how can I resolve this? Any help will be appreciated.

btnlogin code

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool bCheckUser;
            try
            {
               if ((txtUserName.Text == "") || (txtPassword.Text == ""))
                {
                    lblError.Visible = true;
                    lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lblError.Text = "Enter UserName and Password";
                }


                    {
                        bCheckUser = Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, true);
                          FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
                        if (bCheckUser == true)
                        {
                            lblError.Visible = false;
                            Response.Redirect("MainMenu.aspx");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblError.Visible = true;
                            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            lblError.Text = "You Username or Password is Invalid. Please try Again";
                        }

                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
```

on load

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))                   
                    Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx");
            }

        }
```

everytime it is giving Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated as false if i jump form one page to other at start it is giving true then it returns false.

Comment: i got something like this form Stackoverflow itself.. protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) { if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext); } else { filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "AccessDenied" }; } } but its not too working either

Comment: Why not put this information onto the login page when it is redirected to?

Comment: Check this: http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/01/12/redirect-unauthorized-users-to-access-denied-page-instead-of-login-page.aspx FYI: Use edit to add details to your question instead of adding it as comment.

Comment: yup i seen that.. its not working either

Comment: I guess you are talking about asp.net mvc?

Comment: for your FYI: iam not using Login Controls ,so it doesnt takes e. authenticated  instead iam using Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated it gives true at certain instance but again its false when it goes to to other pages..

Comment: You don't have to use Login Control for that to work just using FormsAuthentication is enough. Can you share your code how you are authenticating i.e. your login code?

Comment: There is some duplication in your code but for troubleshooting can you drag and drop a LoginName and LoginStatus control on your login page. Then when you get redirected to Login page after failed authorization, 1) check what is displayed for those controls 2)check what is the ReturnUrl querystring parameter in the address bar

Answer (score 0):

better create a field in ur table like user_type and modify the function which is authenticating the login part as

```
   if(user_type.ToString()=="admin")
       {
             //do other authentication stuff
       }
   else
       {
             Response.Redirect("urerrorpage.aspx");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<location path="Salary.aspx"> 
    <system.web> 
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Salary,Admin" /> 
            <deny users="*"/> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web> 
</location>
there should be comma in allow roles tag
```